# Python Re-Arranging Dictionary for Repetitive Category Names from SQL Query to a Single Category Name as Key

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, dictionary

So I am trying to achieve a dictionary result like:

> {'foo': ({'key': 'value'}, {'key': 'value1'})}

So far I am only able achieve this result with this code:

```
maindict = {}
dict1 = {'key': 'value'}
dict2 = {'key': 'value1'}

maindict['foo'] = dict1, dict2

print(maindict)
```

But I can't use it in a for loop. Tried update() dictionary function, it just overwrites the dictionary.
Is there a way around?

EDITED

Alright folks so here is the original query.
Query returns this:
[image]

Now in python this is how it looks like from sql query:

> [{'id': 1, 'url': '/static/images/dresses/td1.jpg', 'price': 3000,
> 'name': 'product1', 'catname': 'Linen', 'catid': 1}, {'id': 4, 'url':
> '/static/images/dresses/td4.jpg', 'price': 5000, 'name': 'product4',
> 'catname': 'Linen', 'catid': 1}, {'id': 2, 'url':
> '/static/images/dresses/td2.jpg', 'price': 2500, 'name': 'product2',
> 'catname': 'Chiffron', 'catid': 2}, {'id': 3, 'url':
> '/static/images/dresses/td3.jpg', 'price': 4000, 'name': 'product3',
> 'catname': 'Chiffron', 'catid': 2}, {'id': 5, 'url':
> '/static/images/dresses/td5.jpg', 'price': 6000, 'name': 'product6',
> 'catname': 'Chiffron', 'catid': 2}]

I am trying to re-arrange this list of dictionaries in a for loop in a way that every product and its info as value gets nested inside a single key where key is catname(product's category) for instance for Linen category I want it rearranged like:
{'Linen': ({'name': 'product1', 'Price':'xxx'....}, {'name': 'product4', 'Price': 'xxx'}...)}
same goes for Chiffron or any category from the query.
This is how I want to sort query rows in python dictionary. As you can see catname(category of products) has been repeated many times in query. I want to cut that repetition. I want one dictionary for each distinct category and sort the products ands its info under their category by having nested dictionary.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: Updated, I am using sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to collect the rows in lists, grouped by the category name.

```
import collections

maindict = collections.defaultdict(list)

for row in rows:
    maindict[row['catname']].append(row)

for value in maindict['Linen']:
    print(value)

{'id': 1, 'url': '/static/images/dresses/td1.jpg', 'price': 3000, 'name': 'product1', 'catname': 'Linen', 'catid': 1}
{'id': 4, 'url': '/static/images/dresses/td4.jpg', 'price': 5000, 'name': 'product4', 'catname': 'Linen', 'catid': 1}
```

You could do the same with a normal `dict`, but you would need to handle creating the initial list each time you encounter a new key; `defaultdict` takes care of this for you.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! This is what I asked and had to delete my previous post. None helped unfortunately. Some people kept saying its bad practice to have dictionaries with same keys etc etc. Heck, what is the use of dictionaries if a certain key can't hold many nested dictionaries with same ids? Data gets big. Those people misinformed . Anyway, Thank you lots. May you learn more on this journey!